# How can I change keyup value length based on dropdown option?

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is based on each row, so I've it loaded on document like below:

```
$(document).on('keyup','.myNumber',function(){
    var $this = $(this); 
    var lengthA == 16;
    var lengthB == 8;
    var lengthC == 8;
    var lengthD == 10;
    var lengthE == 15;
    var lengthG == 15;
    var lengthH == 10;

    var $row = $this.closest("tr").find('.dropDownSelect');
    if ($row.val() == "Credit Card") { // use $this.val()
        if ($this.val().length == lengthA){
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        } else if ($row.val){}
    } else
        $row.removeAttr("disabled");
});
```

HTML:

```
    <html>
    <table>
    <tr>
    <td>
    <select>
        <option value="1">1</option> //If this is selected, then #myNumber must have 16 digits
        <option value="2">2</option> //If this is selected, then #myNumber must have 8 digits
        <option value="3">3</option> //If this is selected, then #myNumber must have 8 digits
        <option value="4">4</option> //If this is selected, then #myNumber must have 10 digits
        <option value="5">5</option> //If this is selected, then #myNumber must have 15 digits
        <option value="6">6</option> //If this is selected, then #myNumber must have 15 digits
        <option value="7">7</option> //If this is selected, then #myNumber must have 10 digits
    </select>
    </td>
    <td>
    <input type="text" id="myNumber"/> //onkeyup of this the function will run and find out how much integers it has
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
    </html>
```

If dropdown value is lengthA then `myNumber` needs to be 16 characters. `LengthB = 8 characters` and so on.

If they put in a number over or under, I just need an alert saying that.
I'm trying to make a long function like above but I don't think it's going to work at all.

Comment: you need some sort of validation or what?

Comment: `var lengthA == 16;` is not a correct syntax. `==` is used in comparison statement. As you want to assign the value, you should use only `var lengthA = 16;`

Comment: Sorry to say but your question and the code doesn't make sense to me. Can you please describe the [actual problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)?

Comment: I've updated the question a bit to make it clearer, sorry for the confusion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As was mentioned in the comments. To assign a value you should use `=` instead of `==` when you define the variables.

This following will work for one of your lengths. You should edit the code to make it work for multiple lengths as you need. I have added curly brackets arround the jQuery `$` selectors.

Eg: $row becomes $(row).

```
$(document).on('keyup','#myNumber',function(){
var input = $(this); 
var lengthA = 16; // <-- Not == Should be =
var lengthB = 8;
var lengthC = 8;
var lengthD = 10;
var lengthE = 15;
var lengthG = 15;
var lengthH = 10;

var row = $(this).closest("tr").find('.dropDownSelect');
if ($(row).val() == "1") { // use $this.val()
    if ($(input).val().length == lengthA){
        alert('true');
        return true;
    } else {

        return false;
    } 
} else
    $(row).removeAttr("disabled");
});
```

HTML

```
<html>
<table>
<tr>
<td>
<select class="dropDownSelect">
    <option value="1">1</option> //If this is selected, then #myNumber must have 16 digits
    <option value="2">2</option> //If this is selected, then #myNumber must have 8 digits
    <option value="3">3</option> //If this is selected, then #myNumber must have 8 digits
    <option value="4">4</option> //If this is selected, then #myNumber must have 10 digits
    <option value="5">5</option> //If this is selected, then #myNumber must have 15 digits
    <option value="6">6</option> //If this is selected, then #myNumber must have 15 digits
    <option value="7">7</option> //If this is selected, then #myNumber must have 10 digits
</select>
</td>
<td>
<input type="text" id="myNumber"/> //onkeyup of this the function will run and find out how much integers it has
</td>
```

Comment: Sorry, only back now. I'll try it out

Comment: Hi, yes that did work. If you want to just edit myNumer so that it's calling the ID instead of a class in your answer, then it's perfect. Thanks

Comment: Thanks. Glad it helps :)